# How can I efficiently query for contiguous sets of dates in my data set?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
site_id | start_date | end_date
      1 | oct  1, 08 | oct  2, 08
      1 | oct  2, 08 | oct  3, 08
 ...
      1 | oct 30, 08 | oct 31, 08
      2 | oct  1, 08 | oct  2, 08
      2 | oct  2, 08 | oct  3, 08
 ...
      2 | oct 30, 08 | oct 31, 08
```

I have a table that contains 1 record per site per day of the month (per month of the year). I need to be able to determine if a site for a given month has at least 15 contiguous records, and I need to know the start and end date of that series of contiguous days. I can do this in a stored procedure, but I was hoping this could be accomplished in a single query. I am dealing with a fairly large dataset, at least 30 million records per month.

Example Results:

```
site_id | contiguous_start_date | contiguous_end_date
      1 | oct 5, 2008           | oct 20, 2008
      2 | oct 10                | oct 30, 2008
      3 | oct 1                 | oct 31, 2008
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: When does 'end_date' not equal 'start_date + 1 day'?  Because the query is simpler if there is no need to look at both columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do such a query:

```
SQL> create table t (site_id,start_date,end_date)
  2  as
  3  select 1, date '2008-10-01', date '2008-10-02' from dual union all
  4  select 1, date '2008-10-02', date '2008-10-03' from dual union all
  5  select 1, date '2008-10-03', date '2008-10-30' from dual union all
  6  select 1, date '2008-10-30', date '2008-10-31' from dual union all
  7  select 2, date '2008-10-01', date '2008-10-02' from dual union all
  8  select 2, date '2008-10-02', date '2008-10-03' from dual union all
  9  select 2, date '2008-10-03', date '2008-10-04' from dual union all
 10  select 2, date '2008-10-04', date '2008-10-05' from dual union all
 11  select 2, date '2008-10-05', date '2008-10-06' from dual union all
 12  select 2, date '2008-10-06', date '2008-10-07' from dual union all
 13  select 2, date '2008-10-07', date '2008-10-08' from dual union all
 14  select 2, date '2008-10-08', date '2008-10-09' from dual union all
 15  select 2, date '2008-10-09', date '2008-10-10' from dual union all
 16  select 2, date '2008-10-10', date '2008-10-11' from dual union all
 17  select 2, date '2008-10-11', date '2008-10-12' from dual union all
 18  select 2, date '2008-10-12', date '2008-10-13' from dual union all
 19  select 2, date '2008-10-13', date '2008-10-14' from dual union all
 20  select 2, date '2008-10-14', date '2008-10-15' from dual union all
 21  select 2, date '2008-10-15', date '2008-10-16' from dual union all
 22  select 2, date '2008-10-16', date '2008-10-17' from dual union all
 23  select 2, date '2008-10-17', date '2008-10-18' from dual union all
 24  select 2, date '2008-10-18', date '2008-10-19' from dual union all
 25  select 2, date '2008-10-19', date '2008-10-20' from dual union all
 26  select 3, date '2008-10-01', date '2008-10-02' from dual union all
 27  select 3, date '2008-10-02', date '2008-10-03' from dual union all
 28  select 3, date '2008-10-03', date '2008-10-04' from dual union all
 29  select 3, date '2008-10-04', date '2008-10-05' from dual union all
 30  select 3, date '2008-10-05', date '2008-10-06' from dual union all
 31  select 3, date '2008-10-06', date '2008-10-07' from dual union all
 32  select 3, date '2008-10-07', date '2008-10-08' from dual union all
 33  select 3, date '2008-10-08', date '2008-10-09' from dual union all
 34  select 3, date '2008-10-09', date '2008-10-10' from dual union all
 35  select 3, date '2008-10-30', date '2008-10-31' from dual
 36  /

Tabel is aangemaakt.
```

And then the query:

```
SQL> select site_id
  2       , min(start_date) contiguous_start_date
  3       , max(end_date) contiguous_end_date
  4       , count(*) number_of_contiguous_records
  5    from ( select site_id
  6                , start_date
  7                , end_date
  8                , max(rn) over (partition by site_id order by start_date) maxrn
  9             from ( select site_id
 10                         , start_date
 11                         , end_date
 12                         , case lag(end_date) over (partition by site_id order by start_date)
 13                             when start_date then null
 14                             else rownum
 15                           end rn
 16                      from t
 17                  )
 18          )
 19   group by site_id
 20       , maxrn
 21   order by site_id
 22       , contiguous_start_date
 23  /
```

And the results:

```
   SITE_ID CONTIGUOUS_START_DA CONTIGUOUS_END_DATE NUMBER_OF_CONTIGUOUS_RECORDS
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------------------------
         1 01-10-2008 00:00:00 31-10-2008 00:00:00                            4
         2 01-10-2008 00:00:00 20-10-2008 00:00:00                           19
         3 01-10-2008 00:00:00 10-10-2008 00:00:00                            9
         3 30-10-2008 00:00:00 31-10-2008 00:00:00                            1

4 rijen zijn geselecteerd.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: Clever approach to solving problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely very possible.  I solved a similar problem in SQL Server a couple of months ago.  I know nothing of Oracle syntax, so I'm afraid I can't convert if for you, but if you're solid with Oracle, [this](http://thehobt.blogspot.com/2009/04/calculating-elapsed-time-based-upon.html) should be enough to get you there.

Answer (score -1):

Your database structure is not suitable for the business logic you have:

- end_date is always the next day after start_date then why you have to store it in the db?
- I see that in the data sample you gave there is no spaces in dates range for a single site. That means that don't have to store the all dates period just start and stop date.

*30 millions records per month* is really table for the query you have to write.
**Do a structural refactoring of this table** is my advice.