# How can I find contiguous dates within a set of rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with date ranges, some of which are contiguous:

```
COUNTRY START_DATE END_DATE   CODE
------- ---------- ---------- ----
FR      01/05/2014 05/06/2014 07   
FR      05/06/2014 30/06/2014 07   
US      12/05/2010 31/12/2014 08   
FR      30/06/2014 12/01/2015 07
```

How can I find the contiguous ranges within the data? For country 'FR' and code '07' the start date of the second row, 05/06/2014, is the same as the end date of the first row; and the start date of the third row is the same as the end date of the second row, so those three rows are contiguous and I want the overall start and end date across those three records:

```
COUNTRY START_DATE END_DATE   CODE
------- ---------- ---------- ----
FR      01/05/2014 12/01/2015 07
```

Comment: Please include the relevant information directly in the question as text, not just a link to another site (or a picture). Some sample data and expected output would also be useful; it sounds like a gaps-and-islands problem but it's not very clear what you need or what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function to accomplish this. This code is adapted from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937964/how-can-i-efficiently-query-for-contiguous-sets-of-dates-in-my-data-set) and should work for you. It's unclear if the data should be partitioned by country only or by code too (it's impossible to tell from your sample data), but if you need to partition the data by both country and code change the partition by predicates to `partition by country, code order by start_date`instead.

```
select 
  country, 
  code, 
  min(start_date) start_date, 
  max(end_date)   end_date
from ( 
  select 
    country,
    code, 
    start_date, 
    end_date, 
    max(rn) over (partition by country order by start_date) maxrn
  from ( 
    select 
      country, 
      code, 
      start_date, 
      end_date, 
      case lag(end_date) over (partition by country order by start_date)
        when start_date then null
        else rownum
      end rn
    from table1
  ) 
) 
group by country, maxrn, code
order by country, start_date
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4dd4e/4)